# How can i add a list activity instead of a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an application with nav-drawer. When user selects an option from the navigation drawer list, it moves to a fragment. I want to remove this fragment and want to add a list activity with list view as i need to display a list.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        /*// adding nav drawer items to array
        // Full Draw Schedule
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Draw Schedule - Rs. 100/-
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Draw Schedule - Rs. 200/-
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Draw Schedule - Rs. 700/-
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Draw Schedule - Rs. 1,500/-
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        //Draw Schedule - Rs. 7,500/-
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
        //Draw Schedule - Rs. 15,000/-
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
        //Draw Schedule - Rs. 25,000/-
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));
        //Draw Schedule - Rs. 40,000/-
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[8], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(8, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here (50+ will show as a counter infront of "What's Hot")
        //navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));*/


        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Full Draw Schedule
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0]));
        // Draw Schedule - Rs. 100/-
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1]));
        // Draw Schedule - Rs. 200/-
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2]));
        // Draw Schedule - Rs. 700/-
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3]));
        // Draw Schedule - Rs. 1,500/-
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4]));
        //Draw Schedule - Rs. 7,500/-
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5]));
        //Draw Schedule - Rs. 15,000/-
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6]));
        //Draw Schedule - Rs. 25,000/-
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7]));
        //Draw Schedule - Rs. 40,000/-
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[8]));
        //Prize money
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[9]));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here (50+ will show as a counter infront of "What's Hot")
        //navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


        //Recycle the typed array
        //navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 13)
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

I want to replace the following fragment 
**HomeFragment.java**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

with the following list activity
**FullListActivity.java**

```
public class FullListActivity extends ListActivity  {

    TextView content;
    String[] values;
    String theUrl, amount;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_full_schedule);


        content = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output);

        //listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        values = new String[]{
                        "03-08-2015: Rs. 25,000 in Lahore", "03-08-2015: Rs. 7,500 in Rawalpindi",
                        "17-08-2015: Rs. 1,500 in Karachi", "17-08-2015: Rs. 100 in Multan",
                                "Prize"
                };

        // Define a new Adapter
        // First parameter - Context
        // Second parameter - Layout for the row
        // Third - the Array of data

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);


        // Assign adapter to ListView
        setListAdapter(adapter);


    }


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        try {

            // ListView Clicked item index
            //int itemPosition     = position;

            // ListView Clicked item value
            String  itemValue    = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position);


            //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Date: \n" + theUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (values[position].contains("Prize")) startActivity(new Intent(this, PrizeMoney.class));
            else if(values[position].contains("100")) amount = "100";
            else if(values[position].contains("200")) amount = "200";
            else if(values[position].contains("750")) amount = "750";
            else if(values[position].contains("1,500")) amount = "1500";
            else if(values[position].contains("7,500")) amount = "7500";
            else if(values[position].contains("15,000")) amount = "15000";
            else if(values[position].contains("25,000")) amount = "25000";
            else if(values[position].contains("40,000")) amount = "40000";

            theUrl = values[position].substring(0, 10);
            content.setText("Click : \n  Position :" + position + "  \n  ListItem : " + itemValue + "  \n" +
                    "  URL : "+theUrl+"  \n"+"  AMount : "+amount);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: I was 1min away to ask a similar question lol

Comment: Hahahah! Now we both waiting for someone who is able to answer it :D

Comment: Modify  displayView(int position) so it sends the user to the ListActivity when the correct item is selected in the drawer. If you want to maintain a meaningful navigation process for the user, you'll probably need to add the same drawer to your ListActivity to send the user back to MainActivity when another item in the drawer is selected. Nevertheless, I recommend you consider placing your list in a ListFragment instead. Why do you absolutely need ListActivity ? It doesn't look like you're doing a lot of things in your FullListActivity ...

Comment: Well dear i need list activity because i dont know how to create ListFragment. People don't guide beginners :(
BTW! Thanx buddy

Comment: Thank you very much! It actually worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the solution! I am now using ListFragment.

**FullScheduleFragment.java**

```
public class FullScheduleFragment extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener {

    String[] values;
    String theUrl, amount;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_full_schedule_item_list, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                getActivity(),
                R.array.Draws,     //Draws is a string-array in string.xml
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    }

}
```

In side **MainActivity.java**, i just replaced

```
fragment = new HomeFragment();
```

with

```
fragment = new FullScheduleFragment();
```

in

```
private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
        ...
```